# The remote debugger is older than this version of visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting up a new server, and want remotely debug my WPF application from visual studio 2019 ( version 16.1.3 ). I've downloaded the latest remote tools from here 
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2019 
and installed to my remote device.

On the remote device, I've set the authentication mode to " **No authentication** ".
When I try to use attach remote process to visual studio 2019. I get the error as "**The Remote debugger is older than this version of visual studio 2019, upgrade your remote debugger**" though I'm using the latest compatible tools on both sides. Unable to figure out the problem because no help on the internet is available about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out this problem, it's because of older version remote debugger application on the remote machine. You've to be careful which version of remote debugger application you are running for remote debugging.
I mistakenly started the application "remote debugger" which was for visual studio 2017 rather than visual studio 2019.

Comment: thanks , me too, I copied version 2017 instead of 2019 to the server by mistake

Answer (score 0):

I get this error a lot when remote debbuging in Xbox.
According to documentation, “Windows 11 PCs, and Windows 10 PCs running Creator's Update (version 1703) and later, Windows 10 Xbox, IoT, and HoloLens devices install the remote tools automatically when you deploy the app.”

The thruth is that some time I get stuck in the deploy error with the above message. The only way to fix this is to exit develloper mode with "delete side loaded apps and games" checked and then enable developper mode again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).